# Optimize INSERT / UPDATE query on highly indexed tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with an **OpenCart 1.5.6.4** based website which has been highly modified from the original (added indexes, modified queries, you name it, just for performance).

The server is a VPS with **2 x 2GHz processor**, **50GB SSD** and **4GB of RAM**. Currently it has **CentOS 6**, **Apache 2.2.15**, **MySQL 5.1.73**. The website is an online shop with about **50,000 products** and 9 suppliers.

The initial logic of the whole system was:

- import all the products from the suppliers in distinct "buffer" tables
- import all the product categories from the suppliers in distinct "buffer" tables (for mapping purposes)
- update the products in the website ... disable the ones that are not available anymore, or update price, stock for the existing ones based on the rule: "if there's a common product between suppliers, take the lowest price where stock!=0, else take lowest price".

I'm facing some troubles with the update procedure. I've tried some different script ([Select all values that are common between EACH 2 tables on several tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408874/select-all-values-that-are-common-between-each-2-tables-on-several-tables)) but it takes around 3 seconds to run just 1 query.

I don't have much OOP experience so I work with arrays: I load all the product data in one array, I load the exclusion list in other array, I check if the products in the first array are not set in the 2nd one, do the math for the rule and write data with bulk `INSERT [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [...]`.

The whole **update takes ages**, somewhere around **20 seconds** and "eats" **65% CPU** (based on readings in phpmyadmin). I need a solution that: runs very-very fast (and I don't mind the CPU) or takes longer but has lower impact on the CPU ... basically with ~8 connections on the server there is around 50% CPU usage, this means that the original update.php crashes.

I've tried to add `LOCK TABLES product WRITE`, query, `UNLOCK TABLES` but there's a 0.x seconds performance improvement. The UPDATE procedure has around 40,000 products on a single query ... it takes too long, it uses too much CPU and locks tables for a long time.

What can I do about it ?

**LE: code is here** http://inpromo.ro/update.txt

Basically there are 9 distributors, there are site categories and distributors categories (which have to be mapped ... the unmapped categories don't add their products in the website), there are manufacturers which also have to be mapped (the same manufacturer can appear as: ASUS or ASUS Components), things like this ...

**LE2:** One query looks like:

UPDATE product SET stock_status_id=5, quantity=0, status=0 WHERE status=1 OR quantity!=0 OR stock_status_id!=5

It takes 2-3 seconds to complete (according to PHP's microtime() function) and that's a lot!

Comment: Too long question without Code :)

Comment: I doubt that anyone will rewrite that mess for you.A boatload of queries,string manipulations on mysql data,it`s a wonder it only lasts 20 seconds.

Comment: One thing you could do is rewrite subqueries as JOINs `SELECT stuff FROM x WHERE id IN(SELECT stuff FROM y where conditions)` can be written as `SELECT stuff FROM x JOIN y ON conditions WHERE...` Mysql especially 5.1 is very bad at subquery optimization.Also do you have the indexes you need?

Comment: @Mihai: I don't want the actual code (I know there's a complete mess due to client's asking for more and more and not having all the info from the start). I just need an idea on how to make that update work blazing fast ... it's all I'm asking. Thank you!

Comment: @Mihai: ... I've missed the WHERE IN query. Now it's fixed, 1 query going from 0.35s down to 0.018s. Small steps for a big project :)

Comment: Echo your queries and run them separately to find out the slowest one.Lots of work,but its one way to fix it.

Comment: I've tried that also: data processing ~3s, disabling products ~2.5s (say what? It's just "UPDATE product SET status=0" query), bulk update of products ~7s, bulk insert of product_description ~3s ... inserting new products ~22s!!!!!!!!! FML!!! I need to investigate what the hell is going with the new products, but I fear that the queries before that are also slow as hell :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the whole script runs on blocks of code, I've noticed that for all the existing products I've used "INSERT [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [...]" on the indexed tables like: product_description, product_category, product_to_store (these tables don't contain critical data like stock, price) and the whole process took additional 90MB of memory and a bunch of time to process (~12 seconds).

The logic now is:

- INSERT INTO `product` [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [...] (bulk insert/update of all products)
- "SELECT p.product_id, p.sku FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_to_store ps ON p.product_id=ps.product_id WHERE ps.product_id IS NULL AND p.status=1" ... just to load the new items
- insert into product_description, product_category, product_to_store ... details for the new products.

Answer (score 0):

Who's triggering this update?

1) A normal online user

2) A cron job

3) you in the administration?

Maybe you can also post come code lines or the queries you're using.

PS: it's not bad you're not using OOP, but it's bad you work on a OOP platform such as opencart without knowing OOP ....

[read this](http://www.opencartnews.com/interviews/an-interview-with-opencart-founder-daniel-kerr/)

Comment: 1. It's a cron job that triggers the update. 2. I can write/modify OOP based scripts, but somehow I feel uncomfortable in creating objects (perhaps I didn't have the right teacher)

Comment: The idea is that the update must be triggered very often ... now it runs at about 4:00 AM (local time) so it has plenty resources on the server. It must run each hour or so just to keep stocks and prices real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking apparently banal questions, have you tried these things:

- tweaks on mysql and php configurations
- using EXPLAIN statement and try changing indexes
- splitting 'join' queries in small 'non join' queries and then have a look and the 'long query log' to see where id the bottleneck
- are you using 'locks' on table before updating/inserting? (this could be a silly question because opencart could have its own mysql class that does that, but I don't really know)
- try to work on a separate table (with non 'on duplicate key update') and then update the 'live' table (with a simple 'INSERT INTO table_live SELECT * FROM Table_2 GROUP BY someting and bla bla bla you know better')

Hope I've give some ideas.

Comment: I've used all the above except long query log which produces a very big file and uses all the free space on the server. I'm thinking about the solution of writing in a separate table, but here are some problems with data integrity.

Comment: Hi, you can set how many seconds after which a query is considered 'long'. So if you put there 15 seconds (or more) it should clear the log file to a readable lenght.....

Comment: The problem is that I know what scripts are running for long: for example "UPDATE product SET stock_status_id=5, quantity=0, status=0 WHERE status=1" but I need the column `status` to be index.

Comment: 46.500 records from which 37.500 are status=active. If you refer to stock_status_id, there are 5-6 distinct statuses